# Display logged in user's first name onto page (from database)

Tags: database, reactjs, javascript-objects

In preparing a welcome page after a user has logged in, I'd like the page title to display their first name which is found in the user ID database (e.g - "Welcome, Sally!"). This is a bit different than just using a cookie to relay the username in a location; like for example in the top corner to access user settings.

The site is being built with React, if that affects the code needed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you asking how to get the username in the app state? or just how you would render that?

if you already have the firstname in an auth object in state you could do something like this:

```
class WelcomePage extends Component {
   render() {

      const { auth } = this.props

      var pageTitle = `Welcome, { auth.firstname }`

      return (
         <h1>{ pageTitle }</h1>
      )
  }
}

export default WelcomePage
```

otherwise I would need more information to understand what you're asking

Comment: ..thanks! I was able to find another solution for React which I'm posting below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I worked out that seems to do the job. This lies within the React component for the page rendering.

```
  render: function(){
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  ...
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Welcome, {user.firstname1}!</h2>
      </div>
```

Here's a quick screen shot of the result ("Candy" being the logged-in user's first name):
[image]

Comment: awesome! glad you got it working. sorry for not being more helpful!